# Can't create class object as another class' member

Tags: c++

When I try to create an instance of template array stack class of type `_queen` struct as a private member of the `n_queens` class, the compiler throws me these errors:

> error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
>   error: expected identifier before numeric constant

Both at the line  `array_stack<_queen> some_stack(5);`. When I create this stack as global variable, everything seems to be fine.

Why can't I create the stack in the class?

```
#ifndef N_QUEENS_H
#define N_QUEENS_H
#define N 10

template <class T>
class array_stack
{
private:
int top ;
int stack_size;
T* s ;
public:
array_stack(int s_size)
{
    stack_size = s_size ;
    s = new T[stack_size];
    std::memset(s,1,sizeof(T)*stack_size);
    top = -1 ;
}

~array_stack()
{
    delete []s;
    top = -1 ;
    stack_size = 0;
}

void push(T value)
{
 if (top == stack_size - 1 )
  {
    std::cout<<"Stack Full"<<std::endl ;
    return;
  }
top = top + 1 ;
*( s + top ) = value ;
}

T pop()
{
if (top == -1)
{
std::cout<<"Stack Empty"<<std::endl ;
return 0;
}
int temp = top ;
top = top - 1 ;
return *( s + temp );
}

bool isempty()
{
if (top == -1)
    return true;
else
    return false ;
}

void print_stack()
{
if (top == -1)
{
std::cout<<"Empty List"<<std::endl;
return;
}

int i = 0;
while (i <= top )
{
std::cout<< *(s + i++)<< std::endl;
}
}
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
typedef struct
{
    bool fail ;
    int row ;
    int column;
}_queen;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class n_queens
{
    public:
        n_queens();
        virtual ~n_queens();
        n_queens(const n_queens& other);
        void solve();
        _queen initialize_struct(int column,int row);

    private:
    int board[N][N];
    int number_of_queens;
    array_stack<_queen> some_stack(5);
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#endif // N_QUEENS_H
```

Comment: *"why I cant create the stack in the class"* - Because that belongs in the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) of your constructor(s).

Comment: When the compiler sees `some_type some_name(` inside a class definition it expects it to start a member function declaration.

Comment: But ı created an 2d array with no problem

Comment: Can you tell me a workaropund other than defining it as a global variable ?

Comment: [Click the link I put in my first comment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), read that page, then you should be able to fix your code.

Comment: I still couldnt figure it out  :)

Answer (score 0):

What commenter @WhozCraig is saying is that you need to put the `(5)` somewhere else, specifically:

```
n_queens::n_queens() : some_stack(5) { /*existing constructor body*/ }
```